# Obtain average based on multiple criteria from table column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, average, array-formulas

I have a table that more or less looks like this:

```
    Team_Name | Total_Errors | Total_Volume
    _______________________________________
    Sam       |      3       |     1350  
    Sam       |      5       |     1100
    Jamie     |      7       |     1600
    Mark      |      3       |     1220
    Jamie     |      10      |     2100
    Mark      |      5       |     1300
    Sam       |      5       |     1100
    Jamie     |      3       |     1900
```

Just with a lot more rows. **I want to create a formula that calculates the average total_errors for just the numbers corresponsding to Team_names "Jamie" and "Sam".**

How do I do this?

Something like `Average(If(June(Team_Name)="Jamie","Sam"......?`
(the table name is June)

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [`AverageIfs()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sum/Count`:

```
=(SUMIF(A1:A8,"Jamie",B1:B8)+SUMIF(A1:A8,"Sam",B1:B8))/(COUNTIF(A1:A8,"Jamie")+COUNTIF(A1:A8,"Sam"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a simple pivot table that uses `June` as a data source.

Put your `Team_Name` filed as a rows, and `Total_Errors` as Values.  Change the Field settings of your `Total_Errors` to be an average, and change how many decimal points you want to see.

You can then apply whatever filters /Slicers you want and get your desired result.

Here's a screenshot (its on MAC, but you'll get the idea)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DATA in located at `A1:C9` enter this formula at `F5`, note tat the `Criteria Range` used by the formula is locaed at `E2:E4` (see picture below):

`=DAVERAGE($A$1:$C$9,$B$1,$E$2:$E$4)`

[image]